# Can't find JXA documentation

Tags: javascript-automation

where can I find JXA documentation with all available classes, functions and parameters? After so far found just random code samples and short tutorials.

Comment: Really doesn't look like Apple wants to support it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most official source of documentation is the release notes:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/Introduction.html

The WWDC 2014 presentation is also an authoritative source of information:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/306

Answer (score 5):

You can find all the JXA details in the various SDEFs (in Script Editor, menu File > Open > Dictionary...), and in the Apple Release Notes for Yosemite and El Capitan.

But here is a complete list of JXA resources you may find helpful:
[JXA Resources](https://apple-dev.groups.io/g/jxa/wiki/JXA-Resources)